# struggling with django regroup

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have two models.

A project and a backers model.

I want to basically run a query that returns the projects with the most backers.

Is regroup the only way to achieve this?

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.')

class Backer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I've tried the following:

```
{% regroup backers by project as backers_list %}
{% for obj in backers_list %}
    <strong>{{ obj.grouper }}</strong><br />
{% endfor %}
```

although this returns more than expected results.

So i basically want to get the total amount of backers that backed a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with regroup, but the project with the most number of backers is:

```
Project.objects.annotate(Count('backer')).latest('backer__count')
```

Using annotation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

If you wanted the 10 most backed projects, it would be

```
Project.objects.annotate(Count('backer')).order_by('-backer__count')[:10]
```

---

**Update:** I see you might mean "amount" as in the field `Backer.amount`, in which case you would modify the query to use `django.db.models.Sum`.

```
Project.objects.annotate(amount = Sum('backer__amount')).order_by('-amount')[:10]
```